# Why do I see this weird symbol in place of characters in the char array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, char, symbols

output

[image]

I'm getting these weird symbols while trying to display this char array. Same problem in online compiler too. what to do?

It happened once to me in C++ too. Either it shows nothing or this. It's making me crazy.

```
package com.avishkar;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String S = "aeroplane";
        char[] arr = new char[S.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++) {
            arr[i] = S.charAt(i);
        }
        Arrays.sort(arr);
//        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        int count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            char x = arr[i];
            if (x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' || x == 'o' || x == 'u') {
                count2++;
            } else {
                count1++;
            }
        }

        char[] con = new char[count1];
        char[] vow = new char[count2];

        int k = 0, l = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < count1; i++) {
            char x = arr[i];
            if (x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' || x == 'o' || x == 'u') {
                vow[l] = x;
                l++;
            } else {
                con[k] = x;
                k++;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(con));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vow));
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        char[] finArr = new char[count1 + count2];
        for (int i = 0; i < finArr.length; i++) {
            if (count1 > count2) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    finArr[i] = con[x];
                    x++;
                } else {
                    finArr[i] = vow[y];
                    y++;
                }
            } else {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    finArr[i] = vow[y];
                    y++;
                } else {
                    finArr[i] = con[x];
                    x++;
                }
            }
        }

        String ans = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < finArr.length; i++) {
            ans += finArr[i];
        }

        if (count1 - count2 > 1 || count2 - count1 > 1) {
            System.out.println("-1");
        }

        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

Comment: the loop *limits* of `for (int i = 0; i < count1; i++)` are wrong - probably meant to *scan*   the whole `arr`. but `count1` apparently is only the number of non-vowels - [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZyvx.png) with changed *limit* (`arr.length`): `alanepero`

Comment: Some fonts use such a symbol for unprintable characters or for characters it doesn't have a glyph for.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code to print out the hexadecimal value of the characters, rather than the characters themselves.

The output looks like this:

```
0 0 0 0 
61 61 65 65 0 
61 0 61 0 65 0 65 0 0
```

Your "unprintable" characters are hexadecimal zero, which is unprintable.

Here's the modified code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String S = "aeroplane";
        char[] arr = new char[S.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++) {
            arr[i] = S.charAt(i);
        }
        Arrays.sort(arr);
//        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        int count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            char x = arr[i];
            if (x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' || x == 'o' || x == 'u') {
                count2++;
            } else {
                count1++;
            }
        }

        char[] con = new char[count1];
        char[] vow = new char[count2];

        int k = 0, l = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < count1; i++) {
            char x = arr[i];
            if (x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' || x == 'o' || x == 'u') {
                vow[l] = x;
                l++;
            } else {
                con[k] = x;
                k++;
            }

        }
        for (char c : con) {
            System.out.print(Integer.toHexString((int) c) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
//        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(con));
        for (char c : vow) {
            System.out.print(Integer.toHexString((int) c) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
//        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vow));
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        char[] finArr = new char[count1 + count2];
        for (int i = 0; i < finArr.length; i++) {
            if (count1 > count2) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    finArr[i] = con[x];
                    x++;
                } else {
                    finArr[i] = vow[y];
                    y++;
                }
            } else {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    finArr[i] = vow[y];
                    y++;
                } else {
                    finArr[i] = con[x];
                    x++;
                }
            }
        }

        String ans = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < finArr.length; i++) {
            ans += finArr[i];
        }

        if (count1 - count2 > 1 || count2 - count1 > 1) {
            System.out.println("-1");
        }

        for (char c : ans.toCharArray()) {
            System.out.print(Integer.toHexString((int) c) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
//        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```